# how lazy evalution works in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

suppose I have a dataframe, `df1`, which is of size 1 GB and has columns name, age, and city.

Now I want to apply a filter

```py
df2 = df1.filter(df1.age > 23)
df2.collect()
```

Now my question is - what pattern does spark follow? my understanding is that at first, df1 of 1 GB in size is loaded in memory, the condition is checked, and then df2 is created.

Comment: `df2.collect()` or `df2.show()` as well as other actions will cause spark to actually evaluate `df1.filter(df1.age > 23)`

Answer (score 0):

What lazy evaluation is, Spark checks the **Actions (Collect, Show, SaveAsFile, SaveAsTextFile)** in our code. If any one of the Actions is present in the code base, then only Spark will evaluate the **Transformations (grouping, filtering, and map)**.

You may ask questions like, Why does Spark follow this way?
The answer is **If you did not access the output of the transformation that means it wastes the memory to execute the transactions**. Because, if you are not going to perform any action using the output of the transformations then why do we need to execute the transformations? So, *If you perform any **Action** in the code, then only Spark executes all **transformations***.

For more about look at the following documentation
https://medium.com/yavar/apache-spark-transformations-actions-9878ecfc0211